# Pandas extracting text multiple times with same criteria

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I have a DataFrame and in one cell I have a long text, e.g.:

-student- Kathrin A -/student- received abc and -student- Mike B -/student-
 received def.

My question is: how can I extract the text between the -student- and -/student- and create two new columns with "Kathrin A" in the first one and "Mike B" in the second one? Meaning that this criteria meets twice or multiple times in the text.

what I have tried so far: str.extract('-student-\s * ([^.] * )\s * -/student-', expand = False) but this only extracts the first match, i.e Kathrin A.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.split` with regex and defined you delimiters as follows:

```
splittxt = ['-student-','-/student-']
df.text.str.split('|'.join(splittxt), expand=True)
```

Output:

```
  0            1                   2         3               4
0     Kathrin A    received abc and    Mike B    received def.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to try [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall). The only caveat is the result is put into multiple rows instead of multiple columns. With some rearranging this should not be an issue, and please update this response if you end up working it out.

That being said I also have a slight modification to your regular expression which will help you with capturing both.

`'(?<=-student-)(?:\s*)([\w\s]+)(?= -/student-)'`

The only capturing group is `[\w\s]+` so you'll be sure to not end up capturing the whole string.